# How to unsubscribe the NServiceBus subscription?

Tags: c#, nservicebus

If I choose to use the auto subscription in NServiceBus pub sub model, the system does not auto unsubscribe when the client exists.

I can always do a manual unsubscribe, but I having trouble figuring out the existing list of subscriptions and I don't want to hard code the unsubscribe.

So my question is: is there an auto-unsubscribe function in nservicebus?  If not, how can I get a list of current subscriptions for a client?

Comment: rushui out of curiosity why would you want to unsubscribe?

Comment: Have you looked at the TimeToBeReceived attribute - it will guarantee that messages that aren't handled in the given time period will be discarded automatically.

Comment: Hugh - I notice that if the client doe not unsubscribe, publisher will always send out the events to the client msmq.  I don't want the use the network and server resource when the client app is not running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you are going to find an auto-unsubscribe. Udi and company have intentionally designed NServiceBus to make it hard to do things that don't fit the async, pub/sub SOA pattern. Generally, the fact that the client is running or not running would not affect whether or not the subscription is still valid. If that is really what you need, you'll probably have to code that in yourself.

Comment: In essence what you are saying Eric is that in the terminology of Message Oriented Middleware all subscriptions are durable.

Comment: One reason to unsubscribe is if you have implemented a replacement message type and no longer want the old one sent to you any more. But then I suppose one could keep the handler for it, and call `Bus.Unsubscribe(message.GetType())` if one arrives?

Comment: Decommissioning an endpoint is another reason, FWFIW. :)